co-training of agents with message passing
Lets say I have two RL agents (A and B). I want to train 3 A and 1 B to gathere such that afetr each time-step there is a message passing from all A to B and something from B to all A. In other words the agents are connetced as a graph:
enter image description here
I was wondering how to achieve this useng openAi gym inherited environments and stablebaseline3 algorithms (especially SAC).
I think this is quite different from multi-agent RL (MARL), as the agents communicate before making a decision, using a learned code, which is not really multi-agent, but more like splitting a single agent into parts.
Thank you in advance.
Currently, I couldn't find any resources on how to do this.
